# How to use Reference Strings on Port Map?

Tags: mac, minecraft

I play [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net) and use [Port Map](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/portmap/) to host a minecraft server. I was wondering, how do you use the Reference Strings part of it? Does it allow me to create a URL for the server?

If I cannot create a URL in this fashion, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoenstly I only had a super quick look at it, and I couldn't find any reference to the Reference Strings part of it in their wiki, so I'm not sure what that does.

**BUT** if you're after simply getting a URL - it's easy enough. At the moment you're giving out an IP address for your friends to connect to. You want a name (such as myminecraftserver.com) to point to this IP address. You can achieve this via dynamic dns.

1. Go here http://www.dnsdynamic.org/ and sign up for a free account.
2. Download their software and remember the URL you signed up for in the previous process.
3. Run the program on your computer with your sign in details - done!

What this does is gives you a url of your making, and points it to whatever IP address you have on your computer (or where ever you are running a minecraft server). Even if your modem restarts and gives you a new IP the software you're running will update the URL to still point to you.

That way people will always be able to say myminecraftserver.com is your server name.

Comment: Awesome answer! I thought no one would get to it. It's s you a nice little 75pt boost :)